How to set a specific codepage for a non-Unicode app that is not a console app
I have an application that needs the codepage changed to ISO 8859-15.
Changing the codepage at the command prompt with chcp works and text is read correctly.
However the application in question is not running in console, so that's not an option.
I can change the default language for non-Unicode app in Region Settings, but that doesn't let me specify the encoding, only language. There is no language with codepage 28605 as default.
How can I force the system to default to 28605 instead of 437 or 1252 etc.?

Out of curiosity, how did you even end up with an application that requires a codepage that isn't even a standard Windows codepage? Was it deliberately written that way?

The application just takes whatever codepage is the locale standard.
The data I need it to process is, for reasons unknown, delivered in ISO 8859-15.

It's text, though – can you convert the text to another encoding before processing?

No, for two reasons - there's no tools in the pipeline to do this, and just as important if not more, the codepage in use by default on the system simply does not have the requisite characters in it.
